# How to remove default Hover text and display the custom text title on hover Donut chart Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a donut chart created, i have a problem,

1. Shows the inner text titles in two lines for 'meternity :84'.
2. When i hover/mouse over the chart the titles are not displaying as excepted.
   Shows text like 'Series 2' ex: 'Approved Series 2 :84' but needed is 'Approved :84'

I tried using formatter option. but no luck,

Can you guys, please have a look into this and help me out
Link:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/XyQzR/1/][1]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customise the tooltip. An example of what you want is as follows:

```
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '',
            formatter: function() {
                return this.point.name + " :" + this.point.y;   
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUd5L/

As mentioned by another poster, the documentation is pretty good on this stuff, although it doesn't seem to talk much about drilldown objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have control on the display, you just have to add a callback for the tooltip configuration section.

Modify your tooltip section like this:

```
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '',
    formatter: function() {
       console.debug(this.point);
       return this.point.y;
    }
}
```

And you will only display the value of the point object (assuming this is what you want to display).

I added a `console.debug` to show you the content of the point object.

Here is the working example: [highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/XyQzR/4/)

And the documentation page about tooltip : [tooltip on highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)

The documentation of this library is very big but it is a very good documentation (well documented with good examples), so you should be patient and read the documentation (we are not supposed to read it for you ;) )